# Java GUI validation

Tags: java, swing

I have a Java swing application which contains 4 Jtextfields, 1 JLabel and 1 JButton. I want the user to enter integer values in the 4 JTextfields and when the user presses the JButton the sum of the integer values should appear in the Jlabel...Now the main problem is on the JButtons onClickListener i have to validate the JTextfields and i need to know exactly which JTextfield had an invalid entry...I was thinking of implementing a separate try-catch block for each JTextfield and using Integer.parseInt(String s) in the JButton's onClickListener that way i would know which JTextfield is causing problems...But wont implementing a separate try-catch block for each JTextfield be inefficient??? Can anybody suggest a better approach...

Comment: How many try catch blocks validating an integer do you think a computer can execute per second? Is it closer to 4, or closer to 4 millions? If you think its closer to 4 millions, do you think the end user will find your application too slow because it take a millionth of a second to react to a button click?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But wont implementing a separate try-catch block for each JTextfield be inefficient???

Inefficient? That's hardly an issue when you're only checking 4 JTextFields, and shouldn't even be part of your consideration in this instance. Instead, I'd concentrate more on GUI ease of use and safety. Consider preventing the user from entering in non-numeric data in the first place, by using say a JSpinner or JFormattedTextField or by using a DocumentFilter. Consider leaving the JButton, or better, it's Action, disabled, until all four text fields are filled. This will make your GUI more idiot-proof.

---

As per JB Nizet's comment:

> I'd also concentrate on maintainability, and avoid repeating the same block of code 4 times. Use an array or a list to store the 4 buttons, and use a loop to make the same thing for the 4 buttons.

Comment: +1, or course. I'd also concentrate on maintainability, and avoid repeating the same block of code 4 times. Use an array or a list to store the 4 buttons, and use a loop to make the same thing for the 4 buttons.

Comment: Isn't using too many try-catch blocks considered bad programming practice??? i'm just wondering if there's a more mature way to solve this problem...

Comment: @user2423083: not if you absolutely need to know which JTextField is at fault.

Comment: @user2423083 have you read Hovercraft's answer? Re-read it. He's suggesting several better ways.